# SQL - all join statement?

Tags: sql

I am learning SQL and have been tasked with creating a query for this:

-write a select all join statement on userDb.user and userDb.advertiser based on network_id where user_name = 'finance'

However, I cant find anything that suggests an all joint statement so I am confused on what to do?

My attempt so far however, does not work!

```
SELECT userDB.user.network_id,
       userDB.advertiser.network_id
FROM userDB.user
INNER JOIN userDB.advertiser ON userDB.user.network_id = userDB.advertiser.network_id
WHERE network_id = user_name = 'finance'
```

What is the correct code and breakdown explanation?

Comment: You are missing something in where clause
"WHERE network_id = user_name = 'finance';"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, the query you're looking for is something like this;

```
SELECT *
FROM user AS u
INNER JOIN advertiser AS a 
ON u.network_id = a.network_id
WHERE u.user_name = 'finance'
```

You were almost there. The changes I've made is to use table alias' ('u' and 'a') which it's worth reading up on. Your where clause also had too many operators in there.

The SELECT * is what I guess they mean by SELECT ALL

Let me know if you don't understand any of the query above and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: Is it possible without alias?

Comment: sure, just put the table name. The reason I did this is that I'm not sure if userDB is your database name or the schema name. Either way, it's not usually necessary. The naming convention is ServerName.DatabaseName.SchemaName.TableName although you can use just the final one, or the final two, or the final three or all of them.

Comment: SELECT *
FROM userDB.user
INNER JOIN userDB.advertiser
ON user.network_id = advertiser.network_id
WHERE user.user_name = 'finance'

This worked. Cheers for the help, I'll mark this as answer.